# VS Code: Prevent automatic slashes after hitting enter in SCSS file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In a `SCSS` file, I use rows of slashes to separate parts of the code...

```
.MyComponent {
  // ...styles related to concern A

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // ...styles related to concern B
}
```

For a couple of weeks now (writing this in late June 2022), VS Code has started to automatically add three slashes in a new line when I hit enter...

[image]

Why does this happen and can it be turned off?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably some [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) feature for this filetype. It can be customised so you should be able to track that down and disable it.

Or you can just add new line from empty line and not one that have comment.